# how to display google map inside fragment

Tags: java, android-studio, google-maps, android-fragments

so I have `bottomNavigationView` that holds tabs and navigates to fragments using `setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener()`

in one of the fragments I need to display google maps, but I'm getting this error:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.getMapAsync (com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback)' on a null object reference`

even though I initialized SupportMapFragment right above the error line `getMapAsync()` like this : `supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);`

this is how my code looks like

xml:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/my_map"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
    tools:context=".NearbyFragment">
</fragment>
```

and in the java code `(NearbyFragment.java)` I placed the entire code in `onCreateView`:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nearby, container, false);

        supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.google_map);

        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this); // ERROR IN THIS LINE

        client = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(getContext());

        getCurrentLocation();

        return view;
}
```

this the method for `getCurrentLocation();`

```
public void getCurrentLocation() {
        if (..permission == granted){

            Task<Location> task = client.getLastLocation();
            task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    if (location != null){
                        supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                                // init Lat Lng
                                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                                CameraPosition cameraPosition = CameraPosition.builder().target(latLng).zoom(16).bearing(0).tilt(0).build();
                                googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));
                                // creat marker options
                                MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("im here");
                                // add marker
                                googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(getActivity(),
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 44);
        }
    }
```

I'm not familiar with `Fragment` it works when I use it in `Activity` with a bit of changes but I need it in `Fragment` please help

Comment: your map id in XML file is my_map. you try to get  R.id.google_map in your fragment java code.

Comment: I fixed that but still getting the same error @behrad